# Query statement issue , incorrect syntax near WHERE

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

```
 con.Open();
 string query = "INSERT INTO userinfo(username, Name, Phone, Email, Address, Postalcode) values (@username, @Name, @phone, @email, @Address, @postalcode) WHERE username =" + username;
```

Error report:

> incorrect syntax near WHERE

Comment: you use `insert` and `where` together, that's your problem

Comment: Using `WHERE` in an `INSERT` is not allowed and makes no sense anyway. You also forgot to specify any values for the columns. Please do some more studying of examples/training and ensure you understand basic SQL syntax and usage. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to alter an existing record please use an `UPDATE` statement instead. (Also, please ensure you parameterise all input variables into the query, and never concatenate strings as in your example above)

Comment: Are u looking for update the existing records ? then UPDATE can be use

Comment: I am utilizing SQL database in C sharp for web designing, this would be the first insertion into the table itself upon button click for certain parameters whereas username would've already existed in the database upon user registration page, sorry this is my first time posting please forgive me if i made any cultural mistakes here in this site

Comment: You have not made any cultural mistakes, don't worry. But you do need to study the basics of SQL in more detail. As we mentioned earlier, if you are wanting to change the details of a user whose username is already stored in a row in that same table, then you must use `UPDATE`. `INSERT` is only used to create _new_ rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL INSERT statements do not support a WHERE clause.
I assume you are looking for the UPDATE statement instead.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp